# An error "Class 'HttpSocket' Not Found" occured

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm trying to update CakePHP from ver.1.3 to 2.6.

And I found an error using MyLibraryClass.

error is:

```
"Class 'HttpSocket' Not Found"
```

and code is:

```
<?php

class MyApiClient {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->socket = new HttpSocket();
```

So I added this line before class.

```
<?php
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

class MyApiClient {
```

But error is still shown.
Is there anyone who did deal with this case?

Comment: your class should be like class MyApiClientController extends AppController {

Comment: @Er.KT MyClass is under app/Lib Directory. So I can't.

Comment: But you are running in some of the controller so please place  App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http'); at there

Comment: @Er.KT I got it. It worked! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: ok so I am adding it in answer please can you accept it so it will be useful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in comments you have added  following code in app/Lib

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

So please place the same in your required controller before class definition.